# Insight on creating a crosstab query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007, pivot, crosstab

I have a crosstab query in Ms. Access 2007 that I would I like to transition to SQL Server 2008. I'm not familiar with the cross tab approach in SQL, can you guys please provide some insight?

Below is my Ms.Access codes.

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Count([Admit_ID]) Is Null,0,Count([Admit_ID])) AS Expr1
SELECT [Admits].[PatientNumber] & '-' & [Admits].[PlanCode] AS Code]
FROM  Admits
WHERE (((Admits.Admitdate)>="200701") AND ((Admits.Rate)="a"))
GROUP BY [Admits.[ PatientNumber] & '-' & [Admits].[ PlanCode]
ORDER BY [Admits].[ PatientNumber] & '-' & [Admits].[ PlanCode]
PIVOT Admits. Admitdate;
```

The results should be the " Codes" as rows, the "Admit_date" as columns, and the "Admit_ID" as value

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I've never heard of crosstab queries before. Maybe this similar question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946836/crosstab-query-with-count-of-values-in-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: Hi bummi, in Ms. Access it's crosstab, but in SQL the correlating terminology is Pivot I believe.

Answer (score 2):

In order to transform rows of data into columns in SQL Server you will apply the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.

The basic syntax will be the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select a.admit_id,
    code = a.patientnumber + '-'+ a.plancode,
    admitdate
  from admits a
  where a.admitdate >= '200701'
    and a.rate = 'a'
) d
pivot
(
  count(admit_id)
  for Admitdate in (place your dates here)
) piv;
```

The version above will work great if you know the values of the `admitdate` ahead of time, but if you do not know the values, then you will need to look at using dynamic SQL to generate the result.  The code for the dynamic version will be similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(admitdate) 
                    from admits
                    where admitdate >= '200701'
                    group by admitdate
                    order by admitdate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT code, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select a.admit_id,
                code = a.patientnumber + ''-''+ a.plancode,
                admitdate
              from admits a
              where a.admitdate >= ''200701''
                and a.rate = ''a''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(admit_id)
                for admitdate in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: I sorted out the errors, which was due to me not putting brackets [ ] around the dates and a couple of other small things. It works fine now. Thanks for your help.